# A famous, hardworking family

Tags: riddle

We're a group of cousins who live in the same city.

- I live next door to my sister.
- Across the street, four of my cousins live in the same house: a pair of identical twins and a pair of fraternal twins.
- Next door to them, three more of my cousins live in the same house: another pair of identical twins and their little sister.
- My brother, who looks just like me, lives alone way out on the outskirts of town.

Who are we?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like you're:

> Punctuation marks on a QWERTY keyboard

You and your sister are:

> A period/full stop, and the key next to it, a comma

Your cousins:

> Live on the next row up of the keyboard. The first identical twins are the colon, living with (on the same key as) the semicolon (the fraternal twins). Depending on your keyboard, the key next to that has either **"** and **'** or **@** and **'** - presumably you have the former, making the identical twins quotation marks, and their little sister an apostrophe.

Your brother:

> Is the other period/full stop over by the numpad, out on the outskirts of the keyboard

Comment: It's 2015. Who has a numpad? :-)

Comment: I do! It's this one: http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/8487/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/M/B1/MB110LL/MB110LL?wid=1200&hei=630&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1400774915255